# Database back end for mail serrver

Tags: email-server, dovecot

Hi I need to build a front end a mail server and my experience is limited to Dovecot, which I believe doesn't have support for storing mails in databases.  So just thinking how users will be interested in filtering mails for words or sorting mails based on time sent / received, sender, subject, etc it's probably easier to do this via SQL provided the mails are stored in database.  So the question is has anyone setup Dovecot with say Oracle?  And if there are other mail servers that has support for databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not possible with dovecot but their is the [DBMail](http://www.dbmail.org/) imap server that relies entirely on database backends  mysql, postgresql or sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using a DB as a mailstore, instead have a look at the [Lucene](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/FTS/Lucene) and [Solr](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/FTS/Solr) plugins for dovecot.

Comment: Sorry why avoid a dB?  Isn't it more efficient than Lucene?

Comment: Because a DB is very good for containing structured information, mail is much better suited to file system storage.